# Edge Animate Custom Percentage Preloader

Tags: javascript, adobe-edge, preloading

I have an important task that requires me to do a percentage preloading in Edge animate, I looked in the internet and I did not find any tutorials or answers but I found this [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BzhXxn7NLA) video which show how to put a preloader and center it and it uses Loading event which I'm new to it.

but I think that we can use this event to preload the content specially the images which takes a lot of the size.

can anybody give me some code that I can put in this event to preload 3 images for example and show the percentage in a text field (div) in the preload window??

Answer (score 0):

I see this post is old, but have you had any chance finding a solution?
I'd like to hear what you have found...

I'm looking at Zaxist's code from an Adobe forum post which is just 1 month older than your post: https://forums.adobe.com/message/5330716#5330716#5330716

The example files he/she posted work, but the % is not working on my project ATM.

I'm a noob at javascript, so it's unlikely I'll be able to fix this one myself...

Thanks